# how to access 2 api endpoints in the same PHP script and use the results from the 1st to get results from the 2nd

Tags: php, curl

i need to get daily invoice numbers from an api endpoint then use these invoice numbers to get additional invoice guest information.

this code hits the API and returns the paid invoice numbers for 3/8/20

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/api/4.0/invoices?startMin=2020-03-07T00:00:00&endMax=2020-03-08T00:00:00&statusId=PAID",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
   "Accept: /",
   "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic YOUCANTHAVEIT",
   "Cache-Control: no-cache",
   "Connection: keep-alive",
   "Host: api.example.com",
   "cache-control: no-cache"
 ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

$json = json_decode($response, true);
$json = array_values($json['data']);

$codes = array();

foreach ($json as $BKcodes) {

        $codes[] = $BKcodes['code'];

}

curl_close($curl);
}
```

i need to take each of the invoice numbers and pass to a second endpoint to return additional guest details from the booking invoice. i have changed the above code a little added another $curl2 = curl_init(); with the same connection info changing the CURLOPT_URL to

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.example.com/api/4.0/bookings/".$BKcodes['code']."/guests",
```

this works but is painfully slow with only 40 or so invoices.

any direction on a better way would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would look into using a request library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). You just need to make two synchronous calls passing the parsed output from call 1 to call 2. Using curl directly is possible, but it is very verbose and clunky.  To take a stab at your direct question, try using `curl_exec()` and `curl_setopt()` inside the loop for the CURLOPT_URL value you want to change ;)

Comment: If the second API can only accept one invoice number at a time, then yeah, it's going to be slow to make 40 such calls. Consider that you're basically loading 40 web pages in order to do this.

Comment: You have an initial call, plus around 40 subsequent calls. The most efficient method would be to first get the invoice numbers, and then use curl_multi to parallel-process the subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.example.com/api/4.0/bookings/".$BKcodes['code']."/guests");
```

to the loop sped things up, probably because it did not re authenticate every time. 
i am looking into Guzzle thank you @AlexBarker for both, this pointed me in the right direction.

i am also wondering if curl_multi_add_handle() would work in this case.